# Html tag caption disappears when I use the `sScrollY` features of JQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I use the JQuery DataTables and I want to know why my `caption` tag disappears after the first loading of my page.

Here is my Html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link type="text/css" href="Css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/jquery.visualize.plugin.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <select id="Select1" name="D1"></select>
  <br />
  <script>
      $("#Select1").change(function () { getStatistic3(); });
  </script>
  <div id="left">
      <table id="table_statistic_3" class="display">
          <caption class="caption">Omzetcijfer per klant en productgroep</caption>
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <script>fillSlectTagStat3();</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can see that I have a `caption` tag in my table.

I fill the DataTables like this :

```
function fillDataTable3(data, allyearstat3) {

if ($("#table_statistic_3").css("visibility") == "hidden")
    $("#table_statistic_3").css("visibility", "visible");

$('#table_statistic_3').dataTable({

    'aaData': data,
    'aoColumns': [
        { "sTitle": "", "sCellType": "th", "fnCreatedCell": function (cell) { cell.scope = 'row'; } },
        { "sTitle": allyearstat3[0][0] },
        { "sTitle": allyearstat3[0][1] },
        { "sTitle": allyearstat3[0][2] },
        { "sTitle": allyearstat3[0][3] },
        { "sTitle": allyearstat3[0][4] }
    ],

    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "sScrollY": "200px"
});
}
```

You can see the features `sScrollY` in my JavaScript function.

When my page loads the first time, it's work well, my `caption` (=title) is displayed.

But when I select an option in my `select`tag and that my page reloads (with the JQuery function `change`), the `caption`(=title) disappears.

The first time :

[image]

The second time :

[image]

Why? Have you encountered this kind of problem?

ps : When I debug with firebug, I see well, in the generated html, the `caption`tag (when the page loads the first time) and I see well the `caption`tag that disappears when I reloads the page with jQuery function `change`of my `select`tag.

ps : If I remove the features `sScrollY` in my JavaScript function. It works well, I don't have this problem, even when I reloads the page.

Comment: The vertical scrolling option (`sScrollY`) splits the original table into 3 parts: thead, tfoot and tbody are copied to separate divs. I guess the caption might be hidden somewhere or is simply dropped while splitting the table.